# Why could not get any output when use command sudo su -c "sed -n -e '$p' a.txt"

Tags: sed, sudo, su

In Centos 6.7 Linux，I can get one line of output if I run the command:

```
sed -n -e '$p' a.txt
```

[image]

But if I use this command, it has no output:

```
sudo su -c "sed -n -e '$p' a.txt"
```

[image]

Comment: What is the meaning of `$p`. Is `p` a variable or `$p` is a ordinary string? If `p` is a variable, then you if you want to expand the variable to get its value, you should use `"$p"`(double quote), in single quotes, the `'$p'` will not expand to the value of variable `p`, it is literal `$p`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the first command: `sed -n -e '$p' a.txt`. The `'$p'`, the variable substitution is quoted in single quote `'$p'`, then it will contain it's literal meaning, that is literal `$p`, no expansion.

In the second commmand: `sudo su -c "sed -n -e '$p' a.txt"`. The `$p` is included in double quote, though it is included in single quote `''`, but the single quote is just character in double quote. It has no effect on the variable substitution of `$p`. So the variable substitution will be expanded.

For example:

```
p="hello"
echo '$p'    # print $p
echo "'$p'"  # print 'hello'
```

Comment: Thank your help. How to get output with command 'sudo su -c ' to get  last line in a.txt  file?

Comment: Get the last line of a text file can be done with `tail` command. And there is no need to use `sudo su -c`. If the file you wan to read has no read privilege, you can use `sudo` to pretend to be as root to read. So just do `tail -1 a.txt`.

Comment: @nickwu - Why use `su -c` instead of just `sudo tail -1 a.txt`?

Comment: And I have viewed the picture you posted, you are already login as root, so there is no need to use `sudo` or `su` to become root to execute commands.@nickwu